# Changing output format of AVAudioNode

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I'm trying to change the output format of a `AVAudioMixerNode` so that it outputs mono audio at a lower samplerate instead of the default format. Do I have to subclass the `AVAudioMixerNode` class and override the `outputFormatForBus` function to do that, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the docs for [`AVAudioEngine`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioEngine_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioEngine/connect:to:format:) for this method:

```
- (void)connect:(AVAudioNode *)node1 
             to:(AVAudioNode *)node2
         format:(AVAudioFormat *)format
```

Note the `format` parameter:

> If not `NULL`, the format of the source audio node’s output bus is
>   set to this `AVAudioFormat` object. In all cases, the format of the
>   destination audio node’s input bus is set to match that of the source
>   audio node’s output bus.

Specify the mono, lower-sample-rate `AVAudioFormat` whenever the `AVAudioMixerNode` output bus gets connected.

Comment: do you have any idea about my question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53959379/1517943

Comment: AVAudioMixerNode downsampling works, as described in this answer, from 48k to 24k and 16k. However downsampling from 48k to 8k causes  "kAudioUnitErr_TooManyFramesToProcess : inFramesToProcess=512, mMaxFramesPerSlice=320". Environment:  macOS 11.7, Xcode 13.2.1, Target macOS10.15